# gets not waiting for user input in expect script

Tags: tcl, user-input, expect

When i try to run the following expect script, it just finishes running instead waiting for user input. Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
puts -nonewline stdout "Enter device id:"
flush stdout
gets stdin id
puts -nonewline  stdout "Enter device name:"
flush stdout
gets stdin name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expect alters the Tcl `gets` command so that it doesn't wait for standard input; to read a line while waiting for it, you need to do this instead of `gets stdin id`:

```
# Read input to stdin
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set id $expect_out(1,string)
```

Comment: Notes: I found how to get input from the user in the expect documentation, and I confirmed that Expect changes the blocking behavior of `gets stdin` by testing. I was _very_ surprised by that change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
expect "\\$"
puts -nonewline "please enter a swithch user:  "
flush stdout
set userName [gets stdin]
puts $userName
expect "\\$" ;# without this line, the script would exit too fast 
             ;# for the "echo hello" to be sent to stdout by bash
             ;# and thus wont be recorded
```