# TCL / Expect - After Interact, expect_user doesn't echo

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

So I have a simple script that logs into a network device, and then interacts allowing users to call various macros. I have an example below- the user is in the device, hits "!p" and then the script wants the user to input a command.

all works fine, except the program isn't echoing what the user types so it's impossible for them to correct mistypes.

The solution I have currently is `stty echo` before `expect_user` and `stty -echo` after. But in this solution, backspaces and arrow key presses are captured so the user still cannot correct their mistype.

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, but what I assume is happening is the spawned program has control of STDOUT so when expect_user is called, it's in the background.

```
set hostname 10.0.0.1
set password 1234qwer

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $hostname
expect {
        "assword:" {
                        send "$password\r"
                        expect "#"
        }
}
interact {
        "!p" {
                send_user "\nInput command: "
                expect_user -re "(.*)\r" {
                        puts "\n$expect_out(1,string)"
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form, the `interact` command sets up a connection between the user and the currently spawned process. The **user's terminal is put into raw mode** so that the connection is transparent.

*Raw mode* is a specific type of *character-oriented* mode, where no special interpretations are applied to input characters. For instance, Ctrl-C no longer serves as an interrupt, and Ctrl-D no longer acts as an `eof`. The opposite of *raw mode* is *cooked mode*. It represents the most common form of *line-oriented* modes.

So, to achieve what you want, you have to put the terminal into cooked mode before prompting for the input from the user.

```
stty -raw echo; # Put the terminal to cooked mode, echo is enabled.
stty raw -echo; # Put the terminal to raw mode, echo is disabled.
```

Since the terminal is in raw mode for interact, it won't echo the characters at all, which you might have already noticed. i.e. when you type `!p`, you won't see that at all. There is an option available to make it echoed. `-echo` flag with `interact` will do that job.

For example, `interact -echo "Hello" {puts " World"}` will echo `Hello` , while user typing it. This can be added as well to your script.

Adding all these aspects, the finalized code can be written as follows,

```
interact {
         -echo "!p" {
                send_user "\nInput command: "
                stty -raw echo; # Enabling cooked mode
                expect_user -re "(.*)\n" {
                        set input $expect_out(1,string)
                        puts "You have typed : $input"
                        # Process the user input as per your idea
                }
                stty raw -echo; # Enabling raw mode again.
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for answering all my questions. interestingly enough, I tried `stty cooked`  but not `stty cooked echo`.

on a side note, Is there any benefit to using `expect_user` vs `set var [gets stdin]`

Comment: @genx1mx6 : I missed your comment on that other question. Else, could have answered there. By the way, when it comes to `expect`, it is always better to use `expect_user`. Have a look at Mr. Donal Fellows's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10390474) answer.